# Another Power Counting/ mass dimension question

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

Are the mass dimension of the Dirac field different from those of the Klein-Gordon field, or is this just another issue of "cannonical normalization?"

For instance if $\mathcal{L}_{KG}=\int d^4x\partial^\mu\psi^*\partial_\mu\psi+m^2\psi^*\psi$ the dimension of the field is clearly (to me) $d=1$.  With Dirac Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{Dirac}=\int d^4x {1\over 2}i\hbar\left(\psi^*\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi+\psi\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi^*\right)+m\psi^*\psi$, it would appear that the dimension of the field is $d=3/2$.  Is this the correct viewpoint? Thanks.

Comment: They should indeed be different since one is a scalar and the other a spinor field.

Comment: That's something I was wondering about too. Should the fields for fermions have dimensions in terms of ${1\over 2}$ integers?

Comment: Yes. By inspecting the Lagrangian just like you did one concludes that they must.